# how to manipulate XSLT file to only display one div instead of dl with dt's dd's and span's

Tags: xslt

I have a Section in a result from and XSLT file that is like this:

```
<dl class="price-list">
  <dt> </dt>
  <dd class="salesprice">
    DKK <span class="pricethousands">2</span>
    <span class="pricegroupingseparator">.</span>
    <span class="pricehundreds">714</span>
    <span class="pricedecimalseparator">,</span><span class="pricedecimals">40</span>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

I have tried a few times to change the XSLT but i do not seem to be able to change it.

I'd like the result to become something like this or similar:

```
<div>
   <p>DKK </p>
   <p>2.714,40</p>
</div>
```

the xslt is currently using something like this:

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="html">
         <xsl:for-each select="msxml:node-set($list)/product"> 
             <xsl:call-template name="list-product">
                 <xsl:with-param name="list-product" select="."/>
                 <xsl:with-param name="list-vat" select="$list-vat"/>
                 ....
             </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:copy-of select="$html" />
 </xsl:template>
```

I hope you can help me to make this work. I know I haven't provided it all but as it is currently I can't provide more because I'm not allowed to.

```
 <product>
<estocklevel></estocklevel>
<variantof></variantof>
<id></id>
<weightingram>137750</weightingram>
<unit></unit>
<volume>0</volume>
<discountgroup></discountgroup>
<manufactor></manufactor>
<deliverydate></deliverydate>
<url></url>
<texts></texts>
<name></name>
<longdescription></longdescription>
<shortdescription></shortdescription>
<htmltitle></htmltitle>
<metadescription></metadescription>
<metakeywords></metakeywords>
<group></group>
<alternativeitemid></alternativeitemid>
<alternativeitemrule></alternativeitemrule>
<duties></duties>
<priceinfo currency="" price="" standardsalesprice="" vatincludedinprice="False" vatrate="" quantity="">
  <incvat price="">
    <price></price>
    <standardsalesprice></standardsalesprice>
    <discountamount></discountamount>
    <discountpercentage></discountpercentage>
    <vat></vat>
  </incvat>
  <exvat price="">
    <price></price>
    <standardsalesprice></standardsalesprice>
    <discountamount></discountamount>
    <discountpercentage></discountpercentage>
    <vat></vat>
  </exvat>
</priceinfo>
<bulkdiscountpricelist></bulkdiscountpricelist>
<productcategories extra="productcategories"></productcategories>
<indicativedate extra="indicativedate"></indicativedate>
<oncampaign extra="oncampaign"></oncampaign>
<cnt extra="cnt"></cnt>
<weight extra="weight"></weight>
<misc extra="misc"></misc>
<dcurlv2 extra="dcurlv2"></dcurlv2>
```

Comment: The XSLT excert shown above does not contain the relevant portions of your XSLT. I assume that the actual output is generated in a template called `list-product`. Could you edit your question to include that code fragment?

Comment: I cannot see that the List-product is being used anywhere else. this is literally what happens with a lot of in-between code as well as surrounding code. 

A word of warning this is not my code by far I've only come in to a situation where I have to correct this behaviour and I don't know much if anything about XSLT so I'm trying to learn this at the same time of trying to correct this behaviour in to the desired behaviour

Comment: Do you have any `<xsl:include>` tags in your XSLT?

Comment: Nope none. there is a lot of <xsl:variable
a single <xsl:import href="productlist_item.xslt"/> as well as a <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"

Comment: Please show us an example of the XML input.

Comment: there I added the XML input

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed how the actual price of 2714.4 appears in the input. -- Anyway, now search your XSLT for the part where the price is being output; you will recognize it by the expressions "pricethousands", "pricegroupingseparator", "pricehundreds", etc. If it's not in your XSLT, then it will be in the imported productlist_item.xslt document. That's the part you need to change.

Comment: @michael.hor257k
Thank you sooo much if you would be so kind to add this reply as an answer I'll add your answer as the solution. :) 

it was in the imported productlist_item.xslt document that I could change how this was displayed. :)

Comment: Meh. Wouldn't be much of an answer.